# Variable getting empty in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, object, binding, mode

im going to display `value(object-> variable )` from `DB` to view (Select DropDown element) value are being getting from server which is **not empty**  but when i try to console the object object will get value but particular variable which i trying to get

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list     k-data-text-field="'Text'"    k-data-value-field="'Value'"  k-option-label="'-- Select --'"  k-data-source="SchemaValueSource" ng-if="schemaList.length"  ng-model="data.Rules.SchemaId" k-filter="'contains'"  class="full-width m-b form-control" k-on-change="getSchemaFieldsBySchemaId_onChange(data.Rules.SchemaId, data.Rules.DatasetType)"></select>
```

in this `data.rules.Schemaid` get empty

when i try to put another variable instead of `data.rules.Schemaid` then also that variable gets empty

Comment: Please share what you get in data object.

Comment: If possible, include your controller's relevant code